# Is it possible to change modal presentation style for UIAlertController with preferred style UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uialertcontroller, xcode8, uimodalpresentationstyle

I know that you must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem, but I want to show the alert sheet in middle when it's an iPad.

Comment: I have changed modalPresentationStyle and modalInPopover but it did not work. 

I know that the easy solution is to use UIAlertControllerStyleAlert in place of UIAlertControllerStyleAlertSheet.